# How to style Drop Down list items

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Can you guys please tell me how to style drop down list's items? I want to give more spacing between the list items and maybe a border under each item?

```
<select class="text_select" id="field_14" name="field_14" style="opacity: 0;">
    <option value="- Select -">- Select -</option>
    <option value="0 - $2m">0 - $2m</option>
    <option value="$2.1 &ndash; $5m">$2.1 &ndash; $5m</option>
    <option value="$5.1 - $10m">$5.1 - $10m</option>
    <option value="$10 -$20m">$10 -$20m</option>
    <option value="Greater than $20M">Greater than $20M</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not Java related, is Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below jquery plugins, they might help you

[jqtransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

[Nice forms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/)

[uniform](http://uniformjs.com/#themes)

[check more](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm)

[yui niceform](http://freshcutsd.com/yui-niceforms/#yui-niceforms-form2)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JQUERY COMBOBOX](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/combobox)

It is an unobtrusive replacement for the standard combobox that allows the developer/designer to style the control and the option list as well.

easy to setup, default style does not require CSS classes, animated drop-down and it still works with Forms without requiring code changes.

Comment: can you please send me the link to downlod it

Comment: Hmm. Not quite. My form is generated in PHP and I got this code in my page.

<code>    <select class="text_select" id="field_14" name="field_14" style="opacity: 0;"> <option value="- Select -">- Select -</option> <option value="0 - $2m">0 - $2m</option> <option value="$2.1 &ndash; $5m">$2.1 &ndash; $5m</option> <option value="$5.1 - $10m">$5.1 - $10m</option> <option value="$10 -$20m">$10 -$20m</option> <option value="Greater than $20M">Greater than $20M</option> </select>
</code>

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for the stylished drop down [demo](http://www.cult-f.net/elselect/)

Answer (score 0):

/* FIRST ANSWER */

```
<style>
 li {
    /* CODE HERE */
 }     
</style>
```

/* EDIT */

good link => [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Im talking about drop down list (Select) no li

Comment: A drop down list and a list is not the same thing. A drop down list is a type of input where you click on a bar and more options drop down. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list

Comment: @redelman431 I know the difference. I thought he may be confused but gave what he asked for.

Comment: Always assume a user knows what he is talking about until he tells you that he is implying something else. If everyone misunderstands the user's question because of improper terminology, the user will recognize right it's his fault by all the improper answers he gets.

Comment: @redelman431 I read as tho he had made a list and its a "drop down" like a nav bar. and wanted to know how to style that. I guess I miss read thanx

Comment: Ok. Guys this is what I got

    <select class="text_select" id="field_14" name="field_14" style="opacity: 0;"> 
    <option value="- Select -">- Select -</option> 
    <option value="0 - $2m">0 - $2m</option> 
    <option value="$2.1 &ndash; $5m">$2.1 &ndash; $5m</option> 
    <option value="$5.1 - $10m">$5.1 - $10m</option> 
    <option value="$10 -$20m">$10 -$20m</option> 
    <option value="Greater than $20M">Greater than   $20M</option> 
    </select>

Comment: @user1074803 Please update your question and style the information. that is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-item {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:1px;
}
```